# How to get the value of a mysql cell in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cell

I want to get the Value of a MySQL Cell in PHP.
Here is my database table:
[image: values]

[image: structure]

My Code:

```
<?php
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id = :id");
$servers = $statement->fetch();
$server = $servers['id'];
echo $server
?>
```

but it's not doing anything. (I want to get the value of the ID)

Comment: You never set the id for the where startement. and you never execute your statement. see https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php fro more informations

Comment: *"I want to get the value of the ID"* - It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, because the SQL query shown needs you to **give it** the value of `id`.  You're trying to fetch an `id` value that you would need to already have in order to fetch it.  Can you clarify the intent here?

Comment: You won't be able to just guess how PDO functions work. I recommend to check the official manual or follow some (reputable) tutorial.

Comment: And here is one: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchcolumn

Answer (score -2):

use the following query instead of your query

prepare($sql); ``
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);``
$stmt->execute();``
$result = $stmt->get_result(); `enter `
$server= $result->fetch_assoc();``
echo $server; ``
?>